# ECS task_definition environment variable needs IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-ecs

So I have two container definitions for a service that I am trying to run on ECS.  For one of the services (Kafka), it requires the IP Address of the other service (Zookeeper). In the pure docker world we can achieve this using the name of the container, however in AWS the container name is appended by AWS to create a unique name, so how do we achieve the same behaviour?

Currently my Terraform task definitions look like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "${service_name}",
    "image": "zookeeper:latest",
    "cpu": 1024,
    "memory": 1024,
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [
      { "containerPort": ${container_port}, "protocol": "tcp" }
    ],
    "networkMode": "awsvpc"
  },
  {
    "name": "kafka",
    "image": "ches/kafka:latest",
    "environment": [
      { "name": "ZOOKEEPER_IP", "value": "${service_name}" }
    ],
    "cpu": 1024,
    "memory": 1024,
    "essential": true,
    "networkMode": "awsvpc"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about the rest of the setup to give really concrete advice, but there's a few options:

- Put both containers in the same task, and use links between them
- Use route53 auto naming to get DNS names for each service task, specify those in the task definition environment, also described as [ecs service discovery](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/03/introducing-service-discovery-for-amazon-ecs/)
- Put the service tasks behind a load balancer, and use DNS names from route53 and possibly host matching on the load balancer, specify the DNS names in the task definition environment
- Consider using some kind of service discovery / service mesh framework (Consul, for instance)

There are posts describing some of the alternatives. Here's one:

- [How to setup service discovery in Amazon ECS](https://medium.com/containers-on-aws/how-to-setup-service-discovery-in-elastic-container-service-3d18479959e6)